# How to fix the error 'input Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file is not valid'?

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm facing a problem when I deploy a DTSX File to a production server.

In the DTSX file I consume a WebService through the `Web Service Task`, 
The WebService asks for a WSDL File that it has to download from a local path.

There is no problem in my machine, but in the production server it won't ever exists.

I think it is not acceptable to ask to my client to get me permissions to enter in his production server and create a folder to store that wsdl file. In addition what will happen when the wsdl changes? I will have to deploy my dtsx package again and also replace the wsdl file in the server. So I think it is not an option.

So, my question is,

Is there a possible way to avoid to have a physical file with the wsdl especifcation, or it could be deployed within the dtsx deployment package, or save it in a variable, or how else I could do that?

I've been searching a lot, but still not luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this, one option would be to make use of `Script Task` and with the help of .NET namespace *`System.Net.WebClient`*, you can access the WSDL URL path and download the contents of the WSDL file to the system's temporary folder path. You can get the system's temporary folder path, which is the value of the environment variable **`TEMP`**, using the .NET method *`System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`*. The newly generated temporary path of the WSDL file can be then stored in an SSIS package variable, which can then be configured in the `Web Service Task` for it to use instead of relying on a local path. Initially, during development you will need to have the WSDL file in the local path but once you deploy the package to the production, the WSDL file need not exist on the local drive.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 OMG, a very very well explanation of how you did this, And in fact, it helped me to archive my goal, To avoid the path,  I would give you + 10 if I could :D. Thanks a lot for you help and the time you took to answer it. I really owe you one.  Thanks a lot.